# First child css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает first-child.

```css
#one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 0px;
}
#one #two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
#one .all {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
#one .all:first-child(1) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуй написать `#one .all:first-child` вместо `#one .all:first-child(1)`

Comment: @bluepuper Не работает(

Comment: Как минимум нужно еще исправить `gray` на `grey` )

Comment: Судя по всему псевдокласс `:first-child` применяет стили к первому дочернему элементу родителя, то есть в данном случае стили применились бы к первому диву. А так как у этого дива нету класса `.all`, а только `#one` то он и сомневается в присваивании ему стилей. Придется использовать `:nth-child(2)` или как-то по-другому обыграть